# In Alien 3, where is Fiorina "Fury" 161? (pre 2012 sources)

Tags: alien-franchise, alien-3-1992

In *Alien 3*, where is Fiorina "Fury" 161? I'm looking for an in-universe source (excluding *Prometheus*, including everything else) indicating some connection to the real-life night sky.

In various wikis they mention "about 19.5 light years", which would be a nice clue - any idea where that is sourced from? Other clues would be the binary sun, and the assumption that it would be somewhere near a line drawn between Zeta Reticuli and Earth. Outer Veil, unless defined, doesn't help much with finding a real-life star. 
Looking for sources before *Prometheus*, so pre-2012.

Comment: Veil Nebula is a very large, rather faint nebula that covers the entire constellation of Orion and then a bit.  The Orion nebula is a denser region of the Veil.  Some sources call it "Vela" -- the Latin name.

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon: With the Orion Nebula being 1344 light years away, and the Veil Nebula being 2400 light years away, neither would seem to be related to the relatively near-space Alien franchise, sharing the name Veil notwithstanding.

Comment: Just for the record here is a list of the closest stars to earth excluding  alpha, beta and proxima centaur which are only about 4.5ish light years from us... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_star_systems_within_20–25_light-years

Comment: also... whatever it is in alien is specified as being in zeta reticule... https://alienanthology.fandom.com/wiki/Acheron_(LV-426)

Comment: as to where florina 161 is take a look at this... https://www.reddit.com/r/LV426/comments/8ojnb6/star_charts_aka_why_it_makes_no_sense_for_the/

Comment: cannot comment on whether this is accurate or even remotely considered as canon so will leave it just as a comment.

Comment: I found Zeta Reticuli is about 39.5 LY from Earth, so 19.5 LY would be just about halfway from there to here.  Also, it's half the sky away from the Veil Nebula...

Comment: @Zeiss Ikon So where did the 19.5ly used by secondary sources come from?

Comment: @dominic fonde Piecing all these tidbits together in a satisfying way is the hard part.

Comment: @mikeC I'm just going by information in the question.

Comment: If you're still looking for a resource for these locations, then as part of their RPG product line "Free League" or "Fria Ligan" as they are also known has put all locations from all the movies as well as a nice selection from books and comics into a really nice map of space https://alien-rpg.com/

Comment: @IanMcAuley your answer was flagged as spam by our community, but as I don't think you're promoting something you yourself benefit from, I've moved your answer to a comment. Also I did this because your post did not actually answer the question. When you have more reputation you'll be able to post comments by yourself! If you haven't already, please read the [tour] and see how the site works. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

According to the (1992) [*Alien<sup>3</sup> novelisation*](https://avp.fandom.com/wiki/Alien_3_(novel)) Fiorina is in the **Neroid Sector**, situated **within the Outer Veil**.

> Fiorina wasn’t an impressive world, and in appearance even less inviting, but it was **the only one in the Neroid Sector with an active beacon.** The EEV’s data banks locked in on the steady signal. Twice the damaged navigation system lost the beam, but continued on the prescribed course anyway. Twice the signal was recovered. Information on Fiorina was scarce and dated, as befitted its isolation and peculiar status.
>
> ?Fiorina ‘Fury’ 361,?the readout stated. ?**Outer veil mineral ore refinery**. Maximum security work-correctional facility.?The words meant nothing to the ship’s computer. They would have meant much to its passengers, but they were not in position or condition to read anything. ?Additional information requested??the computer flashed plaintively.

Neither of those places exist in the real world, but we can assume that it's somewhere between the supposed location of Zeta2 Reticuli (the in-universe location of LV-426) and Earth.

Comment: Yes, looking for how to connect Fiorina and the Neroid sector with the real world. Are any real world stars mentioned as also being part of the Neroid sector? Any mention of sector size, distance from earth, located in which constellation, or anything like that?

Comment: @MikeC - The "Neroid" sector exists solely as part of the Aliens fictional universe. It doesn't have a real-world counterpart. LV-426 is allegedly orbiting Zeta2 Reticuli, but that star is hundreds (thousands?) of light years from where it should be in reality. Trying to pin these to real-world places is pointless. Per [Bellisarrio's Maxim](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BellisariosMaxim) "*Don't examine this too closely*"

Comment: @Valorum I always wondered why Zeta Reticuli. Is it because of the Barney & Betty Hill "starmap" (which apparently has a better fit with the solar system bodies at that time of this particular Close Encounter of the 3rd (and 4th) kind, I haven't closely looked into that)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer - I can't find much prior usage in scifi before Alien. They may have simply chosen it for its rarity value

Comment: @David Tonhofer - I had heard that the old stories of abductions and crop circles were supposedly by Greys, supposedly from Zeta Reticulli. Some famous psychic supposedly drew a map pointing there. The writers of Alien then chose it based on that connection.

Comment: @MikeC The map comes from a hypnosis session (so free-form association rendered wild). That was way before crop circles and even before "greys" became a meme. 1961 to be precise: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barney_and_Betty_Hill